# What does this specific “Login item” do?

Tags: login-items

I’m troubleshooting a MacBook and looking at the Login items. I see two whose kind is “Unknown” and which have a yellow alert icon next to them. But I have no idea what they are intended to do. How can I get information on them? Is there a text file somewhere in the system that holds the configuration for these items?

(I’m troubleshooting because this computer always tries and fails to connect to an old, discontinued SMB server. It gives the message “there was a problem connecting to the server…“.)

(One of these two login items is called Public, and the other one is the given user’s username, which could be the user’s SMB login.)

This computer is running High Sierra 10.13.6. There appears to be no file for `find ~/Library -iname \*loginitem\*`

Comment: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` exists for me, and shows me all of my login items (on 10.14 and 10.12). Is there are reason you don't want to just delete those entries?

Comment: @At0mic thanks, but I don't want to delete entries before ascertaining what they are. (It's not my computer.) And unfortunately, to restate an earlier issue, there appears to be no `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` for this user on this machine.